# Не отправляет в базу данных комментарий

Tags: python, django

Изучаю django, но даже с примера почему-то не работает

Модель

```
    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
        email = models.EmailField()
        body = models.TextField()
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Форма

```
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

Вьюшка

```
    def post_detail(request, post_id):
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = ""
        # return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {"post":post})
    
        comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment.post = post
                new_comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,
                      'blog/post/detail.html',
                     {'post': post,
                      'comments': comments,
                      'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Код на странице

```
             <form action="." method="post">
                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Add comment"></p>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            payment_request = PaymentQiwi.objects.create(personId=personId, provider=provider, sum_amount=sum_amount, txnId=txnId, status='0', comment=comment)


message_id = message['message_id']
user_id = message['from']['id']
text = message['text']
first_name = message['from']['first_name']
last_name = message['from']['last_name']
User.objects.update_or_create(
    tg_user_id=user_id,
    tg_user_first_name=first_name,
    tg_user_last_name=last_name)
Message.objects.create(
    message_id=message_id,
    user=User.objects.get(tg_user_id=user_id), text=text)


            payment_request = PaymentQiwi.objects.create(personId=personId, provider=provider, sum_amount=sum_amount, txnId=txnId, status='0', comment=comment)

            # Плюсуем баланс
            user.balance = user.balance + payment_sum      
            user.save(update_fields=["balance"])
            # Плюсуем бонус
            user.bonus_balance = user.bonus_balance + payment_sum / 100 * 3
            user.save(update_fields=["bonus_balance"])    
            newbonus = payment_sum / 100 * 3
            payment_request = PaymentQiwi.objects.create(personId=personId, provider=provider, sum_amount=sum_amount, txnId=txnId, status='2', comment=comment)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: может поможет какой нибудь способ